# Using each element of a vector in a series of calculations

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector, calculation

I am trying to write MATLAB code that uses a set of variables in a vector in a calculation.  I am trying to run the same formula with each value in the vector and then store each result in a new vector.

The goal is to calculate and plot the cost of constructing a water tank based on various radius sizes.  In the calculations I have a cylindrical tank and a hemispherical top.  The exact value for the volume of the tank is 500m^3.  The cost of the tank is $400/m^2 surface area for the hemispherical top and $300/m^2 surface area for the cylindrical body.  I know I need to use element wise operators, however I am getting strange, unrealistic results which leads me to believe I am using these incorrectly.

```matlab
rTank = 2:0.5:10;
h = ((250./(pi.*rTank(:)))-((rTank(:).^2)./3));
cost = ((2*pi*400.*(rTank(:).^2))+(2*pi*h(:).*300.*rTank(:)));
plot(rTank,cost)
```

I am expecting a curve of all positive values between radii 2m and 10m, with positive values for cost.  For some reason I am getting negative values for results, and according to the resulting plot, the cost of the water tank is free when the radius is 8m, which makes no sense.

Comment: `h` is negative for larger radii. You should of course discard these impossible solutions.

Comment: I am also confused about your computation of `h`, I think it's wrong. I see: `h = (v - 2/3*pi*r.^3) ./ (pi*r.^2)`, with `v=500` the volume to obtain. That is, total volume minus the volume of the hemispherical top, divided by the area of the base of the cylinder. I presume we ignore the bottom surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter out h<0

```
rTank = 2:0.5:10;
h = 250./(pi*rTank)-1/3*rTank.^2;
good_h=h(h>0);
good_rTank=rTank(h>0);
cost = 2*pi*400*good_rTank.^2 + 2*pi*good_h*300.*good_rTank;
plot(good_rTank, cost)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I didn't realize that for a large enough radius, the height would go negative, which of course would give strange answers.